# Pass function as parameter and bind it to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, bind

I have two files:

**File A:**

```
var A = (function () {
    return {
        bindClick: function (fun) {
            $('#btnId').on('click', fun);
        }
    };
}());
```

**File B:**

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var doSomething = function (what) {
            console.log(what);
        }
        A.bindClick(doSomething(1));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This print me "binded" only once and when I click button nothing happen..

What is the right way to bind a function passing as parameter?

Comment: FYI, instead of `(function($) {  $(document).ready(function() { ... }); })(jQuery);`, you can write `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });` or just `jQuery(function($) { ... });`.

Comment: You're not passing in jQuery to the scope in File A, but you are trying to use it.

Comment: @gpgekko: That doesn't explain the output though.

Comment: Only once? Are you unbinding click event?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/QJZt6/. Please provide more information.

Comment: What browser your're using?

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/FnJPX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that I called:

```
 A.bindClick(doSomething(1));
```

But I was wrong the behavior of the function: it had to return a function, in this way:

```
var doSomething = function(what) {
  return function() {
     console.log(what);
  }
}
```

I hope it will be useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

Besides being somewhat convoluted way of doing things, it seems like it should work. And indeed it does work in the jsfiddles that the commenters have linked to...

I'd guess there is some other code not in your example causing problems. Are there any error messages in the javascript console?

**EDIT:**
The updated code where `A.bindClick(doSomething);` is changed to `A.bindClick(doSomething(1));`, does not work since you're firing the `doSomething` method immediately and bindClick receives the return value `undefined` from that function call.